# Programmatically adding three buttons in line in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a LinearLayout programmatically and I'm adding to this layout three buttons, but they're showed one on top of the other.

How I can show the buttons in line?

Reading around I probably understood that I need to set up a LayoutParams but I didn't figured out how..

I've tried with this but it didn't did the trick..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
);
ll.addView(b1, layoutParams);
ll.addView(b2, layoutParams);
ll.addView(b3, layoutParams);
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

Probably I needed to add more details.

I have also other stuff in the Layout but I does'n matter, I've created an additional layout just for the buttons.

Now the buttons are in line but they have different width.. : /

I've tried with this but it didn't help..

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            1f
);
```

Comment: Hey. I am trying to do something similar to you, and I am having some issues.  I went through this solution and checked what you did, but for some reason I am getting 4 large buttons taking up the full width of the screen, and not appearing in the same row.  Do you think you could have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  http://pastebin.com/26cTEqhg  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Lets you set buttons in horizontal line allignment.

But to give balanced space to all three buttons. you must set `weight` property for all the three `Button` objects to `1`.

Edit:

Do this for all buttons.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = 1;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

to set weight for all buttons.

Regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Now I've my buttons in line but they're are of different width. How can I adjust the weight property?

Comment: in your android layout, add this to your `Button`'s properties `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: How can I  this progammatically?

Comment: Sorry to bother you man but it doesn't work.. the button.getLayoutParams() gives you a ViewGroup.LayoutParams that doesn't have the weight.. : /

Comment: I did it! Just added this to each button:         b2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1)); and setted the parent layout weigth to 3! ; )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

All have MATCH_PARENT should have  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT in width or height (in at least one as per LinearLayout orientation )

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    LinearLayout gvDivisao = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gvDivisao);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LayoutParams btDivLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

    Button btDivA = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_divisao, null);
    btDivA.setText("A");
    gvDivisao.addView( btDivA, btDivLayoutParams);
```